# Netflix eureka client micro-service is not registering with eureka server

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am trying to register my microservice with the eureka server. But it shows no instances available in the browser. I do not get any error in the console. Please help me in resolving this.

I already tried multiple options by searching on google. Still, I am unable to resolve the issue.

Microservice application.properties

```
  spring.application.name=jecreations-core
  eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

client main class

```
 @EnableEurekaClient
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableConfigurationProperties(ImageProperties.class)
 public class JecreationsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(JecreationsApplication.class, args);
}
 }
```

Eureka Server application.properties

```
   eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
   eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
   server.port=8761
   spring.application.name=DiscoveryServer
```

Eureka server main class.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableEurekaServer
 public class JeeurekaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(JeeurekaApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with dependency of eureka client.
I have given this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

instead of

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: I did the same mistake. This answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate the eureka server main class with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient

public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Additionally you need annotate you client's main class with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MicroApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

You need the below configuration in application.yml of the eureka client:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

In the Eureka Server application.yml file I have this configurations:

```
info:
  component: Eureka Server

server: 
  port: 8761


eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 15
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
```

Comment: I tried bilal. Still, I am unable to register. I am seeing an unknown error in eureka-server pom.xml. There are no resolutions also for that.

Comment: Did you add required dependencies: "<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

eureka server config

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka= false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

eureka client config

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress= true
```

Still facing the problem please follow my repo 
https://github.com/vimaleshJeyavelmani/spring-boot-micros

Thanks,
Vimalesh

Comment: Yes, Vimalesh I tried this one also. Still, I am unable to register it. jecreations-core application is a child of jecreations application.